# matplotlib not displaying bar chart not centered when I shrink the frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm implementing a candlestick chart with vertical line plot and bar plot:

```
plt.bar(date, height, linewidth=0.8, bottom, color=color, zorder=0.2)
plt.vlines(date, low, high, color=color, linewidth=0.5, zorder=0.1)
```

I get a candlestick chart just like this:
[full chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkXPK.png)

which is what I wanted.
Then if I shrink the size of the window I get this:
[shrinked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta4yK.png)

which looks like some bars are off-centered and doesn't seem to draw a full bar in some instances.

Any solutions for the shrinked version to look more like the full screen version?

Comment: does just using `vlines` (or maybe `bar`, instead of both) do the right thing?

Comment: @Sam Mason using ```vlines``` alone does seem to be working, however using ```bar``` alone causes the same problem: [image](https://imgur.com/a/qe5IWNc)